# WooCommerce return product object by id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a custom theme for woocommerce and I need to be able to create a mini product display. I am having problems finding documentation on the woocommerce api. I have a comma delimited list of product IDs that I need to iterate through and display a custom mini product display for each in sequence.

```
$key_values = get_post_custom_values('rel_products_ids');
//get comma delimited list from product

$rel_product_ids = explode(",", trim($key_values, ",")); 
// create array of just the product ids

foreach ( $rel_product_ids as $pid ) { 
    //sequentially get each id and do something with it

    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $pid ) );
    // also tried ...
    //$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'ID' => $pid ) );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $_product = &new WC_Product( $loop->post->ID );
        //do stuff here I have stripped the html in favor of getting to the meat of the issue
        woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $_product );
        if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_single');
        get_permalink( $loop->post->ID );
        the_title(); 
        $_product->get_price_html();
    endwhile;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Tim

Comment: Woocommerce docs can be pretty sparse, usually just list functions and parameters with no real explanation

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Another easy way is to use the WC_Product_Factory class and then call function get_product(ID)

http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product_Factory.html#16-63

sample:

```
// assuming the list of product IDs is are stored in an array called IDs;
$_pf = new WC_Product_Factory();  
foreach ($IDs as $id) {

    $_product = $_pf->get_product($id);

    // from here $_product will be a fully functional WC Product object, 
    // you can use all functions as listed in their api
}
```

You can then use all the function calls as listed in their api:
http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

Comment: Oh they have a factory for the products, that is exactly what I needed. Works like a charm, thank you.

Comment: @Jacy Mok is there any way in woocommerce to get products from API rather than from database??

Comment: Woo have fully fladged API for shop vendor (not for clients). https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

Answer (score 133):

Use this method:

```
$_product = wc_get_product( $id );
```

Official API-docs: [wc_get_product](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_wc_get_product)

Comment: This is the actual way to do this. There's no need to create a WC_Product_Factory each time, as there's an instance there all the time in use by WC.

Comment: how I can get_permalink if I use this method ?

Comment: @huykon225 No need to invoke WooCommerce: `$link = get_permalink($id);`

Comment: New api doc link: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_wc_get_product

Answer (score 5):

Alright, I deserve to be throttled. definitely an RTM but not for WooCommerce, for Wordpress.
Solution found due to a JOLT cola (all hail JOLT cola).

TASK:
Field named 'related_product_ids' added to a custom post type. So when that post is displayed mini product displays can be displayed with it.

PROBLEM:
Was having a problem getting the multiple ids returned via WP_Query.

SOLUTION:

```
$related_id_list          = get_post_custom_values('related_product_ids');
    // Get comma delimited list from current post
$related_product_ids      = explode(",", trim($related_id_list[0],','));
    // Return an array of the IDs ensure no empty array elements from extra commas
$related_product_post_ids = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 
                                   'post__in'  => $related_product_ids,
                                   'meta_query'=> array( 
                                        array( 'key'    => '_visibility',
                                               'value'  => array('catalog', 'visible'),'compare' => 'IN'
                                        )
                            ) 
);      
    // Query to get all product posts matching given IDs provided it is a published post
$loop = new WP_Query( $related_posts );
    // Execute query
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $_product = get_product( $loop->post->ID );
    // Do stuff here to display your products 
endwhile;
```

Thank you for anyone who may have spent some time on this.

Tim

Comment: You should change `new WP_Query( $related_posts );` with `new WP_Query( $related_product_post_ids );` . Cheers!

Comment: `get_product` has been deprecated and should be replaced with `wc_get_product`

Answer (score 0):

```
global $woocommerce;
var_dump($woocommerce->customer->get_country());
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $product = new WC_product($cart_item['product_id']);
    var_dump($product);
}
```

Comment: I'm sure it will help if you explain what the code does and how it answers the question

Comment: DO NOT use this, because woocommerce products can be variable and each product type has their own class.